# Dynamic 3 years graph in Power BI as per incremental year

Tags: powerbi-desktop

How can I create dynamic graph lines in Power BI which shows only three graph lines?

I used filters, but it will not work for every future year. As in, currently restricted it between 2019-2021. But how this can be handled dynamically for year 2022, for every incremental year?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a visual level filter as shown below to achieve your desired output. This will always show the last 3 years' data in the chart:

[image]